# what's the latest version of VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is the Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel latest?

Comment: I am currently running that version. I cannot confirm right now whether or not it's the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_2010#Visual_Studio_2010) page on Wikipedia, in the infobox at the top of the page, the latest stable release is **2010 RTM (10.0.30319.1)**. There may be later versions available as Hotfixes or pre-releases of service-packs.

There doesn't appear to be anywhere on microsoft.com that documents the latest version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7):

**as of November 2014:**  Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Comment: As of February 2017 still: Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
I think no more updates are coming for VS 2010

Answer (score 5):

as of 22nd Feb 2013:  10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Comment: Isn't that the same as Noah's answer.......

Comment: The question is "what is the latest version of VS2010 ?" and 2 years after Noah's answer, I just verified it was still 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel for the sake of comfirmation.

VS2010 probably reach EOL.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/DownloadResults.aspx?q=visual%20studio%202010%20service%20pack&sortby=-availabledate seems to show 3 additional updates....

Comment: If so, as of 28th April 2014, the latest version of VS2010 is... ?
You know, the answer to this question can change anytime.

Anyway, what's the point of asking latest version of some products ? Are we having some compatibility issues with VS2010?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the final RTM version. Be the piece with you.

Comment: I think he still needs to get SP1

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel

Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 RTMRel